# Real-time TeX editor

Tags: editors

I am looking for an **offline**, real-time-rendering TeX editor similar to what you find at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. It would be nice to have the ability to edit, save, and render the complete document offline, without requiring the reader to install any libraries. (so `.html` or `.pdf` format would be acceptable)

Has anyone managed to create and share an offline implementation of MathJax or similar?

Comment: MathJax is not TeX; it just interprets a subset of TeX syntax

Comment: MathJax is _not_ TeX: do you just want MathJax-like rendering or _real_ TeX.

Comment: sorry I'm not that well-versed in TeX. All I would like is, a MathJax-like renderer that can edit and save the TeX renderings offline.

Comment: Also: Gummi, WhizzyTeX.

Comment: Figure out one way to do this: go to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. Open Adobe (or equivalent) PDF app. Copy, paste, done.

Comment: I have a solution for you but since the question is closed I can't answer it. If you want something equivalent to StackExchange editor, there is at least one Markdown editor that can be made to behave almost identically. It is called `ReText`. In Fedora you can install it with `dnf install retext mathjax`. Run it,  activate Live Preview (`CTRL+L`), `Edit -> WebKit renderer` then type something like this "Hello \\(x^2\\)". You can export to HTML, ODT, or PDF. Source: https://github.com/retext-project/retext/wiki/Math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Android apps on Google Play could do this, so I wrote an android app that does all these things. It's [out on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TeXEditor.TeXEditor_full&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5UZVhFZGl0b3IuVGVYRWRpdG9yX2Z1bGwiXQ..) now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered paying for [BaKoMa TeX](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/)?

I cannot vouch for how good it is, though.